# Add Hourly Employee Via QuickBooks API

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

How can I set the hourly rate via the API with quickbooks?  I don't see anything about it in the Docs:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/Employee

I see a mention about the billable rate, but that's not the same.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$EmployeeService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Employee();
$Employee   = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Employee();
$Employee->setGivenName('Greg');
$Employee->setFamilyName('Mathis');
$Employee->setSSN('311-22-1111');
$Employee->setAddress('828 Test Avenue');
$Employee->setTitle('Mr');
$Employee->setHourlyRate('30000');

$Address = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryAddr();
$Address->setLine1('72 E Blue Grass Road');
$Address->setLine2('Suite D');
$Address->setCity('Mt Pleasant');
$Address->setCountrySubDivisionCode('MI');
$Address->setPostalCode('48858');

$Employee->setPrimaryAddr($Address);

$resp = $EmployeeService->add($Context, $realm, $Employee)
```

This works to add the employee, but there's no hourly rate.  I've tried various plays on "HourlyRate" "HourlyPayRate" and I've tried to look at the forms in quickbooks panel for possible hints to no avail.

Is it possible to set the hourly rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "hourly rate" field available via the QuickBooks Online API. You can see the supported fields for employees in Intuit's documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/employee

Note that if you're subscribed to the QuickBooks Payroll service, Employee-related functionality is limited via the API because most of this is handled by Payroll service, and not via QuickBooks directly.